# Spring mvc validation rest

Tags: spring, validation, model-view-controller

Hi I have this method over here now i want to perform validation for this with how to do it can anyone explain i am new to spring.I am using json to bind value to Employee using @Requestbody and I want to validate all fields and json array if any field has errors.

```
var json = {"employeeid" : empID,"employeename" : empName,"joiningdate":joinDate,"emailid":emailid,"experience":experience};  


 {@RequestMapping(value = "/CreateEmployee.web",method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String CreateUserThroughAJAX(@RequestBody String json)throws IOException}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:

```
class Employee {
@NotNull
private Integer employeeid;
@NotNull
@Length(min=3, max=50)//not sure that it is correct annotation
private String employeeid;
... etc
}
```

And controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/CreateEmployee.web",method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String CreateUserThroughAJAX(@RequestBody Employee employe)throws IOException
```

Spring will parse your JSON and create valid entity, or will send "Bad Request" to your client as response (400 HTTP status).

Answer (score 0):

firstly define your your POJO backing bean with your validation constraints (more [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html)), eg:

```
public class Employee {

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    // rest of fields + getters & setters

}
```

then change controller method signature as follows:

- change parameter type from `String` to `Employee`
- provide `@Valid` annotation for automatic validation check

---

```
public String CreateUserThroughAJAX(@Valid @RequestBody Employee obj)
```

Comment: But how to add all errors along with Field name and send json as response

Comment: spring itself (in case of failure) handle exception and send json response with given exception, if you want to customize error response its another question.. check e.g. https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc